# Multiple @NoBinding values

Tags: validation, playframework

Basically:
Can my model classes contain @NoBinding annotations with multiple values?

If I have this model:

```
@Required @Email public String email;
@Required @Min(8) @Max(64) @Equals("repeatPassword") public String password;
@Transient public String repeatPassword;
@Required public String firstName;
public String middleName;
@Required public String lastName;
@NoBinding("signup") public boolean isFlagged;
@NoBinding("signup") public boolean isAdmin;
```

I really need something like: `@NoBinding("signup", "signupOther") public boolean isAdmin;`

But unfortunately that doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@NoBinding({"signup","signupOther"})
```